# Python and Firefox (Windows) - How to save a page as I see it

Tags: python, windows, firefox

I am trying to implement automation in Python, because they changed the way we access data in my work. We used to log into an Unix based terminal, while now by using a simcard we open a browser page in Firefox that emulates the terminal.

Here is my problem: I wrote a script to save a .txt file with the data I am interested in. But when I tried to run it at work, it didn't run, because the page wouldn't let me open it (even if I was logged in).

So I decided to use a dumb solution: I saved the Firefox page as it was open and ran the script locally. But... I can't find how to save the page opened in Firefox without having to type the URL in Python beforehand. I want to automate this step too.

Is there a way to save the page opened like this one, acting like a `Ctrl + S` shortcut?

I appreciate any kind of help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried urllib? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html

Comment: Hi! Yes, I've tried... I can't open the URL, that's the problem...

Comment: Did u find the solution for this Ctrl + S shortcut?